# Delete array of cookies (WebExtensions)

Tags: javascript, cookies, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am currently working on developing a WebExtension (for Firefox/Chrome/Opera) that will remove all cookies from a list of domains and its subdomains. The problem I am facing is that I cannot find a way to pass an array of domains. I tried:

```
var gettingAllCookies = browser.cookies.getAll({domain: myArray});
```

,

```
var gettingAllCookies = browser.cookies.getAll({domain: [{"www.example-0.com.cn"}, {"www.example-1.com.br"}, {"www.example-2.com"}]});
```

and

```
var gettingAllCookies = browser.cookies.getAll({domain: "www.example-0.com.cn", "www.example-1.com.br", "www.example-2.com"});
```

Nothing seems to work. Need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that domains have that format ".example.com".

One solution is to iterate on your domain array like this:

```
const domains = [".youtube.com", ".google.com"]

const doThingsWithCookies = function(cookies) {
    ...
}

for (let d of domains) {
    browser.cookies.getAll({domain: d}).then(doThingsWithCookies)
}
```